# Unable to use $_SESSION in an other file (PHP)

Tags: php

Hello good afternoon, I'm having the trouble of not being able to use add a $_POST value to my $_SESSION variable so that I can use it later in my profile file.

- I can give it other values like "hello" outside the if and it echoes hello in levraiprofilewesh.php.
- I've tried making $_SESSION a super global variable and global but it didn't work.
- I've been stuck on it for a few hours :(.
- I don't need to upload the website on the web, it's just for local use, so there's no need for privacy feedback although it has helped me for the future.

login.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();   
include("db_connect.php"); 

if(isset($_POST['login_button'])) {
    $user_email = trim($_POST['user_email']);
    $user_password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $_SESSION['password'] = $user_password;
    $usql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='$user_email' && Password='$user_password'";
    $uresult = mysqli_query($db, $usql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($db));
    $urow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($uresult);
    //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($uresult)) 
    //$STPMARCHEFRERE = $row['Firstname'];
    //$SESSION = $row['Firstname'];
    
    if($urow['Password']==$user_password){
        setcookie("userid",$user_password,time()+(60*60*24*7));
        setcookie("useremail",$user_email,time()+(60*60*24*7));
        //$GLOBALS['SESSION'] = $user_password;
        $time=time();
        $queryz = "UPDATE Users 
                    Set Online='Online',
                        Time='$time' 
                    WHERE Password='$user_password' ";                        
        $db->query($queryz) or die('Errorr, query failed to upload');   
        echo "ok";   
    } else {                
        echo "email or password does not exist."; // wrong details 
    }       
}
?>
```

levraiprofilewesh.php code:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include("login.php");
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','phpchart');
if(isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['password'];
    $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM users 
                WHERE Password = '%$username%'";

    $select_user_profile_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_profile_query)) {
        $post_tamere = $row['Firstname'];
        $post_tondaron = $row['Sirname'];
        $post_tasoeur = $row['Phone'];
        $post_tonneveu = $row['Institution'];
        $post_julia = $row['Email'];    
    }
}
?>
    
    
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['edit_user'])) {
    $user_firstname = $_POST['user_firstname'];
    $user_lastname = $_POST['user_lastname'];
    $user_role = $_POST['user_role'];
    
    //$post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    //$post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
    //$post_date = date('d-m-y');
    //move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "./images/$post_image" );
    
    $query = "SELECT randSalt FROM users";
    $select_randsalt_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$select_randsalt_query) {
        die("Query Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
       
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_randsalt_query); 
    $salt = $row['randSalt'];
    $hashed_password = crypt($user_password, $salt);
 
    $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $query .="user_firstname  = '{$user_firstname}', ";
    $query .="user_lastname = '{$user_lastname}', ";
    $query .="user_role   =  '{$user_role}', ";
    $query .="username = '{$username}', ";
    $query .="user_email = '{$user_email}', ";
    $query .="user_password   = '{$hashed_password}' ";
    $query .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
          
    $edit_user_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
       
    confirmQuery($edit_user_query);
}    
?> 
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Welcome to Profile
                            <small>Author</small>
                        </h1>
                        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title">Firstname</label>
                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $post_tamere; ?>" class="form-control" name="user_firstname">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="post_status">Lastname</label>
                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $post_tondaron; ?>" class="form-control" name="user_lastname">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="user_role" id="">
                                    <option value="subscriber"><?php echo $user_role; ?></option>
<?php 

    if($user_role == 'admin') {
        echo "<option value='subscriber'>subscriber</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='admin'>admin</option>";
    }

?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
          
                        <!--<div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="post_image">Post Image</label>
                                  <input type="file"  name="image">
                            </div>-->

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="post_tags">Phone</label>
                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $post_tasoeur; ?>" class="form-control" name="username">
                            </div>
      
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="post_content">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" value="<?php echo $post_tonneveu; ?>" class="form-control" name="user_email">
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="post_content">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" value="<?php echo $post_julia; ?>" class="form-control" name="user_password">
                            </div>
                        <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['superhero']; ?></h1>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="edit_user" value="Update Profile">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please post code into your question as text. Pictures of code are no use if someone wants to copy/paste them in order to write an answer

Comment: PLease dont sote Plain Text Passwords in your database. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: If you use the password in the where clause (you shouldn't be using it but you are) and you get a row back from the table, there is little point is checking in an IF that it is the same as what the user entered, because you already used it in the WHERE clause

Comment: You should NEVER be placing a password into a cookie, even if it was hashed

Comment: Basically this code needs a total rethink followed by a rewite. There are tutorial out there on the web, be careful some of them are good, but most are just click bait

Comment: Is it just the $_SESSION['password] variable that's not working?

Comment: ___so there's no need for privacy feedback___ So you want to learn how to do it wrong and then learn how to do it right? **That makes sense :(**

Comment: s it just the $_SESSION['password] variable that's not working? YES I can't give it the $_POST data

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: so there's no need for privacy feedback So you want to learn how to do it wrong and then learn how to do it right? That makes sense :( No but I'm too hungry to know how to be able to make my levraiprofilewesh work.

Comment: Ahhh Once you have done a `edit_user` the password on the database is HASHED :) **`password_hash()` and `password_verify()` would be easier and more reliable**!!! But in the login, you try and select the user using the UN-HASHED user entered password ..... ___See comment 2 and 3___

Comment: ___And finally___ Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!